# Eclipse editor replaces spaces,tabs, new lines with gibberish

Tags: eclipse, editor

[image: Eclipse Editor Problem]

The problem: As you can see, the editor 'replaces' spaces, tabs and new lines with weird characters.

What I tried to do to fix the problem:

- Reboot PC, start eclipse again.
- Change editor theme.
- Restore default settings at Appearance tab.
- Tried to check other projects, same problem.

And I have no clue how to fix it, as there is no answer in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 'show whitespace characters' enabled. The characters are not 'gibberish' they are showing you things like tab and new line characters.

Open the Preferences and go to 'General > Editors > Text Editors' and deselect the 'show whitespace characters' option. You can also configure exactly which characters are shown here.

There is also a button on the toolbar for this.